# rails エラーの解決をお願いします。

Tags: ruby-on-rails

`rails server` で起動させようとしたところ、エラーが出ましてサイトの読み込みができません。
どのように解決すればよいでしょうか？
回答いただけますと幸いです。

～以下コード～

```
ec2-user:~/environment/kensaku (master) $ rails s
=> Booting Puma
=> Rails 5.2.4.4 application starting in development 
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
Puma starting in single mode...
* Version 3.12.6 (ruby 2.6.3-p62), codename: Llamas in Pajamas
=> Booting Puma
=> Rails 5.2.4.4 application starting in development 
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
Puma starting in single mode...

ec2-user:~/environment $ cd kensaku
ec2-user:~/environment/kensaku (master) $ rails s
=> Booting Puma
=> Rails 5.2.4.4 application starting in development 
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
Puma starting in single mode...

ec2-user:~/environment/kensaku (master) $ rails s
=> Booting Puma
=> Rails 5.2.4.4 application starting in development 
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
Puma starting in single mode...
* Version 3.12.6 (ruby 2.6.3-p62), codename: Llamas in Pajamas
* Min threads: 5, max threads: 5
* Environment: development
* Listening on tcp://localhost:8080
Use Ctrl-C to stop
^[d^C- Gracefully stopping, waiting for requests to finish
=== puma shutdown: 2021-01-22 16:35:13 +0000 ===
- Goodbye!
Exiting
^[dec2-user:~/environment/kensaku (master) $ ^C
ec2-user:~/environment/kensaku (master) $ ^C
```

Comment: "～以下コード～"のあとに書かれているのは、プログラムコードではなく、実行時のコンソール出力なのでは？

Comment: どの部分を見てエラーと判断されていますか？  / また、`Listening on tcp://localhost:8080` と表示されたタイミングでブラウザから `localhost:8080` を開くとどうなるでしょうか？

Answer (score 0):

> Version 3.12.6 (ruby 2.6.3-p62), codename: Llamas in Pajamas Min
> threads: 5, max threads: 5 Environment: development Listening on
> tcp://localhost:8080 Use Ctrl-C to stop

メッセージを見る限り、railsアプリ動いているようですが？